# JavaScript: On Paste file,clipboard data is empty

Tags: javascript, copy-paste

I use **'Paste'** event by jQuery for listening to the user when he press `ctrl + v`.
When a user pastes an image - it works well, I get the file at event.clipboardData.files[0], but when I paste file - `excel`, `.txt`, etc. - the files array length is 0  = I get no file.

What is the problem with my code?

```
    $('#' + pasteZoneId).bind("paste", (e)=> {
        //my code...
    });
```